# Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claims creates a new Persistent Volume instead of binding to the available Persistent Volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, docker-for-mac

I am running mac OSX Catalina using the docker application with the Kubernetes option turned on. I create a PersistentVolume with the following yaml and command.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.1.250
    path: "/volume1/docker"
```

> kubectl apply -f pv.yml

This create and PersistentVolume with name pv-nfs-data. Next I then create a PersistentVolumeClaim with the following yaml and command

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-nfs-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

> kubectl apply -f pvc.yml

This create a PersistentVolumeClaim with the name pvc-nfs-data however it doen't bind it to the available PersistentVolume (pv-nfs-data). Instead it creates an new one and binds it to that. How do I make the PersistentVolumeClaim bind to the available PersistentVolume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Docker for Mac [default storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#defaultstorageclass) is the [dynamic provisioning type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#dynamic), like you would get on AKS/GKE, where it allocates the physical storage as well.

```
→ kubectl get StorageClass
NAME                 PROVISIONER          AGE
hostpath (default)   docker.io/hostpath   191d
```

For a PVC to use an existing PV, you can disable the storage class and specify in the PV which PVC can use it with a `claimRef`.

#### Claim Ref

The PV includes a `claimRef` for the PVC you will create

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  claimRef:
    namespace: insert-your-namespace-here
    name: pv-nfs-data-claim
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.1.250
    path: "/volume1/docker"
```

The PVC sets `storageClassName` to `''`

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv-nfs-data-claim
  namespace: insert-your-namespace-here
spec:
  storageClassName: ''
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

#### Dynamic

You can go the dynamic route with NFS by adding an [NFS dynamic provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs),   create a [storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) for it and let kubernetes work the rest out. More recent version of Kubernetes (1.13+) can use the [CSI NFS driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-nfs)

Comment: When make your changes I get the following error. Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "pvc.yml": namespaces "wherever" not found

Comment: replace `wherever` with the required namespace on your cluster in both definitions, or remove it from both definitions if you don't mind what namespace can claim the PV.

Comment: I just noticed something. If I run kubectl get PersistentVolumeClaims the claim seems to be stuck in a Pending status. Is there way to force it to a Bound status?

Comment: That normally happens automatically when it's available. There's likely another problem. Check the kubelet logs, I'm not sure where they go on docker for mac.